# Chiamare un forestiero con il nome della sua città, regione o paese è considerato un insulto?

Tags: word-usage

Nel racconto *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, il bambino Gesú, quando si trova in Egitto, viene chiamato "Palestina" dagli altri bambini. Per esempio, in questo brano:

> Al mattino Jesus si sveglia, non c’è la madre, il padre è sortito, si infila le braghe, prende un tocco [pezzo] di pane, e va fuori nella strada: ci sono tanti bambini che corrono avanti e indietro, che saltano, giocano.
>   
>      – Fate giocare anche me al vostro gioco?… Fatemi giocare… io sono bravo!
>    
>      – Va’ via **Palestina**!

D'altra parte, nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante, quando Lena, l'io narrante, si trova studiando a Pisa racconta questo fatto:

> Poi successe che un pomeriggio, in un caffè di via San Frediano, davanti a parecchi studenti, uno dei miei corteggiatori respinti mi gridò serio, mentre uscivo con due mie compagne: «**Napoli**, ricordati di riportarmi il pullover blu che ho dimenticato da te». Risate, uscii senza replicare.

La mia domanda è: chiamare un forestiero con il nome della sua città, regione o paese, come negli esempi sopra citati, è o era considerato offensivo o ingiurioso? Se è cosí, questo tipo di insulto si usa ancora oggi?

Comment: Direi di sì,  è offensivo: è come specificare che sei un estraneo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direi che sì, è di solito da considerare offensivo in quanto implica i seguenti messaggi:

- sei un estraneo
- nemmeno mi sforzo di chiamarti per nome
- non sei il benvenuto

Naturalmente, dipende anche dai rapporti e dalla familiarità tra chi parla: tra persone che si conoscono bene potrebbe essere anche utilizzato in modo scherzoso (ma questo vale anche per altri tipi di epiteto).

Non saprei indicare l'attuale diffusione, ma non penso possa essere considerato passato di moda (considerazione personale).

Comment: Fra amici potrebbe essere solo un modo scherzoso, altrimenti è certamente offensivo.

Comment: Penso dipenda molto dal contesto. Quand'ero alle superiori circa metà delle persone in classe mia erano chiamate dai compagni con il nome del paese da cui venivano. L'ho sempre trovato un po' strano, ma non era fatto con l'intento di insultare.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Potresti fare un esempio di quello che hai detto?

Comment: @Charo In che senso? Per esempio un mio compagno di classe era chiamato *Marano*, perchè veniva da [Marano di Mira](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marano_Veneziano) (ho fatto le superiori a [Mirano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirano))

Comment: @DenisNardin: Volevo dire appunto questo, grazie.

Comment: aggiunta precisazione sulla base del commento di @DenisNardin